# Tiles Game Best Practices

Tags: c#

Coming from a software engineering background I don't have so much experience developing games. Below is a simple 2d tile connect game.
What would people improve about it? What are some good practices that could be applied here and what would people suggest?

**Board.cs** - main script that handles setting up and resetting the board.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour {

    // Board Lengths by Cells   
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public GameObject[] tilePrefabs; // array of different tiles which may be used (different colours)
    public GameObject[,] allTiles; // a 2d array of all the tiles on the board

    private TileAnimations tileAnimations;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
        tileAnimations = this.GetComponent<TileAnimations>();
        allTiles = new GameObject[width, height];
        Setup ();
    }

    // Generate board of random tiles
    private void Setup (){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);

                // Create tiles
                int tileToUse = Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length);
                GameObject tile = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[tileToUse], tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                tile.transform.parent = this.transform;
                tile.name = "(" + i + ", " + j + ")";

                // Add tile to tiles array
                allTiles[i, j] = tile;
            }
        }
        //bool deadlock = this.GetComponent<DeadlockChecker>().CheckDeadlock();
    }

    // check for null spaces and populate them
    public IEnumerator CollapseColumnCo(){

        int nullCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                if(allTiles[i,j] == null){ // when you create a chain, there will be null spaces on the board (since the tiles disappear)
                    nullCount++;
                }
                else if (nullCount > 0){
                    allTiles[i, j].GetComponent<Tile>().tileY -= nullCount;
                    StartCoroutine(tileAnimations.SlideDown(allTiles[i,j], nullCount)); // slide down tiles above null spaces
                    allTiles[i, j - nullCount] = allTiles[i, j]; // update position in allTiles
                    allTiles[i, j] = null;
                }
            }
            nullCount = 0;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
        StartCoroutine(FillBoardCo()); // refills board
    }

    private void RefillBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (allTiles[i, j] == null) {
                    Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
                    int tileToUse = Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length);
                    GameObject piece = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[tileToUse], tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    piece.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0);
                    StartCoroutine(tileAnimations.ScaleTile(piece, "expand"));
                    allTiles[i, j] = piece;
                }
            }
        }
        //bool deadlock = this.GetComponent<DeadlockChecker>().CheckDeadlock();
    }

    private IEnumerator FillBoardCo() {
        RefillBoard();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
    }

}
```

**Link.cs** - state of a chain

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Link : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 touchPosition;

    public List<GameObject> chain = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject chainHead;

    private Board board;
    private TileAnimations tileAnimations;

    public bool chaining = false; // is the player in the middle of creating a chain?

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        board = FindObjectOfType<Board>();
        tileAnimations = this.GetComponent<TileAnimations>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){

    }

    // Pops tiles when chain is destroyed
    public void DestroyChain(List<GameObject> linkedChain){
        StartCoroutine(tileAnimations.PopIt(linkedChain));       
    }

}
```

**Tile.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tileX;
    public int tileY;

    private Board board;

    public bool inChain = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        board = FindObjectOfType<Board>();
        tileX = (int)transform.position.x; // column number
        tileY = (int)transform.position.y; // row number
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (inChain == true) {
            this.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1.5f, 0);
        } else {
            this.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0);
        }
    }

    // Checks adjacency so you can only make chains with tiles which are next to each other
    public bool IsAdjacentToHead() {
        // if on left of head
        if (tileX == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileX - 1)
            && tileY == board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileY) {
            return true;
        } else if (tileX == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileX + 1)
            && tileY == board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileY) {
            // if on right of head
            return true;
        } else if (tileX == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileX)
            && tileY == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileY + 1)) {
            // if on top of head
            return true;
        } else if (tileX == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileX)
            && tileY == (board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>().tileY - 1)) {
            // if on bottom of head
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(){
        board.GetComponent<Link>().chaining = true;
        inChain = true;
        board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead = this.gameObject;
        board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Add(this.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(){
        board.GetComponent<Link>().chaining = false;
        if (board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Count >= 3){
            board.GetComponent<Link>().DestroyChain(board.GetComponent<Link>().chain);
            board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Clear();
        } else {
            // Remove all from chain
            foreach (GameObject x in board.GetComponent<Link>().chain){
                x.GetComponent<Tile>().inChain = false;
            }
            board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter(){
        // Only if we are chaining AND the tile does not alread exist in the chain
        if(board.GetComponent<Link>().chaining == true && !board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Contains(gameObject)){

            // Make sure the tile to be connected is adjacent to the head AND have same colour (tag)
            if (IsAdjacentToHead() && this.CompareTag(board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.tag)) {
                board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Add(this.gameObject);
                board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead = this.gameObject;
                inChain = true;
            }
        }

        // If the next tile is the one previous in the chain (penultimate element) - remove last element
        if (board.GetComponent<Link>().chaining == true) {
            if (this.gameObject == board.GetComponent<Link>().chain[board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Count - 2]) {
                board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead = this.gameObject;
                // remove last element from chain
                board.GetComponent<Link>().chain[board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Count - 1].GetComponent<Tile>().inChain = false;
                board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.RemoveAt(board.GetComponent<Link>().chain.Count-1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**TileAnimation.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destroyEffect;

    private Board board;

    void Start() {
        board = FindObjectOfType<Board>();
    }

    // After chain disappears, tiles above slide down
    public IEnumerator SlideDown(GameObject tile, int nullCount) {
        var originalPos = tile.transform.position;
        var finalPos = tile.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, nullCount, 0);
        float t = 0f;
        float timeToMove = 0.2f;
        while (t < 1) {
            t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
            tile.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originalPos, finalPos, t);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Destroy each tile with a delay
    public IEnumerator PopIt(List<GameObject> linkedChain) {

        float destroyDelay = 0.1f;
        foreach (GameObject tile in linkedChain) {
            int tileX = tile.GetComponent<Tile>().tileX;
            int tileY = tile.GetComponent<Tile>().tileY;

            StartCoroutine(PopOut(tile, destroyDelay));

            board.allTiles[tileX, tileY] = null;
            destroyDelay += 0.1f;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds((linkedChain.Count + 1f) * 0.1f);
        StartCoroutine(board.CollapseColumnCo());
    }

    //  Shrink tile down + Particle Effect
    public IEnumerator PopOut(GameObject tile, float delay) {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        GameObject particle = Instantiate(destroyEffect, tile.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(particle, .6f);

        StartCoroutine(ScaleTile(tile, "shrink"));

        Destroy(tile,0.2f); // wait for shrink animation before destroying
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleTile(GameObject tile, string action) {
        var originalScale = tile.transform.localScale;
        Vector3 finalScale = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);

        if (String.Equals(action, "shrink")) {
            finalScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        } else if (String.Equals(action, "expand")) {
            finalScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Only expand and shrink actions can be used with ScaleTile script.");
        }

        float t = 0f;
        float timeToMove = 0.2f;
        while (t < 1) {
            t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
            tile.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, finalScale, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return null;
    }

}
```

Any tips/help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just curious--why did you remove the cool screen capture showing how the app works?

Answer (score 4):

I have some tips regarding C# conventions.

- Public fields should be replaced with public properties and should be title-cased. For insance `Board.width`, `Board.height`.
- Think about whether certain fields should be encapsulated within the instance and can only be mutated by methods on the instance. `Tile.tileX`, `Tile.tileY` are good candidates to encapsulate to avoid letting other classes changing these values out of bounds.
- Don't repeat class name in variable names. `Tile.tileX` should be called `Tile.X`.
- Use formatted string where possible: `$"({i},{j})"`. In this particular, case you could have used a `ValueTuple` `(i, j).ToString()` to get the same output.
- Be consistent with white space, parentheses: at one moment you have 3 consecutive methods with 3 different styles of white space `Setup (){`, `CollapseColumnCo(){`, `RefillBoard() {`.
- I don't get why you have an empty method `void Update(){` which is not an interface implementation.
- Some *if* statements could be replaced with ternary operators to avoid redundant code: see  `this.gameObject.transform.localScale` in method `Update` and condition `inChain == true`.
- Conditions should not be checked against true/false: `if (inChain == true)` should be written as `if (inChain)`.
- Cache redundant calls in a local variable: `board.GetComponent<Link>().chainHead.GetComponent<Tile>()` should be cachec before all the `if` statements in `IsAdjacentToHead`.
- Some of your loops could be refactored to use LINQ: `foreach (GameObject x in board.GetComponent<Link>().chain)` `x.GetComponent<Tile>().inChain = false;`. See `IList<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action)` extension method.